# How to store images efficiently?

Tags: image, server, storage

I am developing an application. I created a service that transforms images into WebP, and I need to store them on an optimizer server like S3, which is open source and easily deployable.

I looked at Imgproxy, but I think it does too much; I just need to store images.

Comment: What "efficient" do you mean? Little storage space, fast reading and/or writing, something else? Can you explain why that "Imgproxy" does "too much"? However, this question seems off topic for SO

Comment: 1. Imgproxy does cropping, resizing, and a lot more. He will use lots of RAM for "useless" actions, so I search for something more lightweight.
2. I mean fast and lightweight (ram, CPU) by efficient. The important thing for me is to get images fast, with if possible some caching for "popular" images.